# JLabel not updating with SetText

Tags: java

I'm a complete newbie to java, so this question may sound really dumb. My apologies for not being able to find an answer myself... I tried, but couldn't figure out what the issue is. :'(

[image]

```
public class ViewIncomePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private HeadQuarter headQuarter;
private JPanel viewIncomePanel;
public static final String NAME = "ViewIncomePanel";
private JLabel amountMessage;
private JLabel totalAmountMessage = new JLabel();
private LoadCompletePanel loadCompletePanel;
private MonthlyIncome monthlyIncome;
private JButton backButton;
private NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

public ViewIncomePanel(HeadQuarter userControl) {
    this.headQuarter = userControl;
    monthlyIncome = userControl.getMonthlyIncome();
    this.viewIncomePanel = this;

    JPanel incomePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));

    double value = headQuarter.getTotalIncome();
    String s = Double.toString(value);
    amountMessage = new JLabel("Total amount is: ");
    amountMessage.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    amountMessage.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);

    totalAmountMessage.setText(s);
    totalAmountMessage.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    totalAmountMessage.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);


    backButton = new JButton("Back");
    incomePanel.add(backButton);
    incomePanel.add(amountMessage);
    incomePanel.add(totalAmountMessage);

    backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            goBack();
        }
    });

    viewIncomePanel.add(incomePanel);
    incomePanel.setVisible(true);

}

private void goBack() {
    headQuarter.getScreen(loadCompletePanel.NAME);
}
```

Here is my code. The issue is with totalAmountMessage; so for my code, every time I input an income the total amount of income should sum up. But my code always returns 0 when I run it. Funny thing is, when I tried printing out headQuarter.getTotalIncome() it worked fine. So the issue lies on getting the value printed with JLabel.

Here is my MonthlyIncome class:

```
public class MonthlyIncome {

private List<CurrentIncome> allIncome; // list of monthly income
double total; // monthly total income
double incomeDay;  // income for specified day

public MonthlyIncome() {
    allIncome = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addIncome(CurrentIncome i) {
    allIncome.add(i);
}

public void findIncomeDate(int date) {
    incomeDay = 0;

    for (CurrentIncome i : allIncome) {
        if (i.getDate() == date) {
            incomeDay += i.getIncome();
        }
    }
}

public double getIncomeForDate() {
    return incomeDay;
}


public double totalIncome() {
    total = 0;

    for (CurrentIncome d : allIncome) {
        total += d.getIncome();
    }
    return total;
}

public double getTotal() {
    return total;
}
```

And here is my HeadQuarter class:

```
private MainGuiPanel mainGui;
private double incomeAmount;
private int incomeDate;
private double expenditureAmount;
private int expenditureDate;
private ExpenditureType type;
private CurrentExpenditure currentExpenditure;
private MonthlyIncome monthlyIncome;
private CurrentIncome currentIncome;


public HeadQuarter(MainGuiPanel mainGui) {
    this.mainGui = mainGui;
    monthlyIncome = new MonthlyIncome();
}

public void getScreen(String name) {
    mainGui.getCardLayout().show(mainGui.getHolderPanel(), name);
}

public void addExpenditure(Double amount) {
    this.expenditureAmount = amount;
    currentExpenditure.setAmount(amount);
}

public MonthlyIncome getMonthlyIncome() {
    return monthlyIncome;
}


public void recordExpenditureDate(int date) {
    this.expenditureDate = date;
    currentExpenditure.setDate(date);
}

public void makeCurrentIncome(int date, double amount) {
    incomeAmount = amount;
    incomeDate = date;
    currentIncome = new CurrentIncome(incomeDate, incomeAmount);
    monthlyIncome.addIncome(currentIncome);
}

public void makeCurrentExpenditure(int date, double amount) {
    incomeAmount = amount;
    incomeDate = date;
    currentIncome = new CurrentIncome(incomeDate, incomeAmount);
    monthlyIncome.addIncome(currentIncome);
}

public double getTotalIncome() {
    return monthlyIncome.totalIncome();
}
```

Any helps will be appreciated! Sorry again for asking such a stupid question. But I'll be really grateful if anyone can help me out!

Comment: setText set the text once. It doesn't bind the label to the value and it won't auto-update when the value changes

Comment: @jhamon Aha, I see. Thanks so much for your comment! What should I do to fix this issue then?

Comment: Invoke setText() when the value changes.